# Sucre vs. Sucré

Tags: grammaire, anglais, suffixes

In recent times, I have been noticing that certain words in french have a form where the same word ending with an "e" will have another form of it but ending with and "é". I assume that this is like the difference between "employer", and "employe" in English, but I'm not sure. If possible, could you tell me what grammatical aspect or category this is?

Comment: It is very simple: sucre = sugar (noun), sucré = sugary/sweet (adjective). This works for a lot of words, sometimes it's noun-adjective/past participle, sometimes it's verb in present-adjective/past participle.

Comment: http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/sucre  //  http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/sucr%C3%A9   // http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/employer  //  http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/employ%C3%A9  //

Comment: *Le sucre est très sucré...* Although they are said differently, due to the accent.

Answer (score 5):

If you look up the [definition](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sucre/75200) of `sucre`, you'll see it is a noun meaning `sugar`.

`Sucré` however, according to the [dictionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sucr%C3%A9) is an adjective equivalent to `sweetened / sweet`. Example:

- This juice is very sweet! (*Ce jus est très sucré*)
- Sweetened milk (*Du lait sucré*)

`Sucré` can have other meanings:

- Act as an adverb: 'Manger sucré' (ie: 'mettre du sucre sur ses aliments')
- Act as noun: (see the second link provided)

`Employé` is the person who is employed, whereas `Employer` is the verb meaning 'to employ'.

Hope this helps!